# Query builder - IN function returning zero rows

Tags: qgis, query

I have a layer of several areas (polygons) each having a unique number, I want to make a new layer only containing some of the areas. I made a duplicate of the original layer and went to query builder and tried the following expression:

```
"n2000_nr" IN ('16','17','18','24','30','33','35','39','41','48','49','52','53','57','68','76','95','114','173','186','233')
```

But when I test it, it returns zero rows. I tried only selecting the 5 first areas and that went fine.
Is there a limit or what is the problem?

Comment: What's the data type of the "n2000_nr" field? If it is numberic then try without the single quotes around each value.

Comment: When i hover the mouse over the field "n2000_nr" i says "Real NULL"?

Comment: Try your expression without the single quotes around the values and see if that works.

Comment: I get this warning: An error occurred when executing the query, please check the expression syntax.